# How to Access NYC ACRIS Real Property Master via SODA2

Tags: socrata, soda

How do we access NYC ACRIS Real Property Master via SODA2?

To recreate the issue:

go to: (step 1)

https://data.cityofnewyork.us/City-Government/ACRIS-Real-Property-Master/bnx9-e6tj

Navigate to Export -> SODA API - API Docs

you will end up here: (step 2)

https://dev.socrata.com/foundry/#/data.cityofnewyork.us/bnx9-e6tj

We see this authorization screen and even after allow'ing the same screen appears again and again, it seems to be in a loop.  Can you help?  This works for tiny files but not the ACRIS Master File, it appears.

[image]

Here's a picture of step 2 above:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the [ACRIS Real Property Master](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/City-Government/ACRIS-Real-Property-Master/bnx9-e6tj) filtered view is a bit of a weird case that the City of New York has set up for their data.

That filtered view (denoted by the blue "funnel" icon you see at the upper left) is actually a limited access version of a dataset that has been made private, hence the page asking you to authenticate before viewing the API docs for the base dataset.

You can make a limited class of queries through the API endpoint for the filtered view itself:

```
https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/bnx9-e6tj.json
```

What are you looking to do?

Comment: Thanks.  I was wondering about the blue funnel.  It appears the all the ACRIS city register data endpoints are on 2.0.  Can they be upgraded to 2.1?   And why would NYC DOF make a public dataset "private"?  Can we ask NYC DOF or our NYC CTO to make it public.  These are important datasets :)  Thanks for your help.   I have a related question about the usage of $where which I'll post to stackoverflow.

Comment: I figured out the where syntax but it appears that IN is also only part of Soda 2.1   Another reason to upgrade the ACRIS datasets.  Who controls this upgrade?  We the developers, NYC or Socrata?  Thanks again.

Comment: Correct, ACRIS is only available as a SODA 2.0 endpoint, so the `IN` operator isn't available. Unfortunately, the city controls when the 2.1 endpoint will be made available, and I don't know what their internal schedule is for that.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for your answers though!

Comment: Did anyone ever figure out how to access data like this in real time? It seems like this data set is not real time. I'm guessing there must be something out there that is closer to real time, or at least a day delayed or something. Any ideas?

Comment: @j413254 We need to advocate for better information in government transparency.  Please do contact me.  ralph@tidalforce.org